# camera movement in SWTOR

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I want to turn my camera to look to another direction than the direction I am walking without having to hold down a mouse-button.

When I turn my camera to look sideways (without turning my character to that direction) and then start walking, the camera always turns itself to get straight behind my character and make me look forward.

This is the default setting in WoW too, but you could turn of this automatic behaviour.

I would like to turn this behavior off in SWTOR too. Sadly, I can't find a setting for this. Have I missed that setting when searching for it, or is this not possible?

Comment: I think you didn't miss anything and it's just not possible (at least at the moment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you have not missed anything.

Unfortunately, at this moment, there is no configuration option that allows you to change this camera behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Turn off the option "Smart Camera" under **Preferences -> Controls -> Camera** and the camera will stop rotating behind you.